# Changing a view doesn't automatically reflect on page

Tags: web-part, list-view

We've got a simple view for a list. When we add/remove columns, the view doesn't automatically reflect the changes; we have to go to the publishing page, click Edit Web Part, and re-select the view in the web part's "Selected View" dropdown.

Is there a way to get a list view to automatically reflect the changes? What are we doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the normal behaviour of a Listview-webpart. You did nothing wrong. Everytime you edit the list, you should edit the listview webpart. I know it's annoying (hate it myself)...

Options to solve this:
Eventhandler on the list. When the list changes, the event is triggered and you update the webpart's view.

Code to change webpart:
http://spblog.net/post/2011/04/26/Changing-default-view-for-ListViewWebPart-programmatically.aspx

Comment: Thanks, RubenHerman. This is very annoying! Wondering if SP2014 will fix this.

Answer (score 1):

This is true.  The web part doesn't actually show the view, but instead duplicates the view in a web part.  The actual view itself could be deleted, but it would still show up in the web part because it was duplicated.  If there is no need for the actual view itself, the best thing to do is when you first insert the web part, just edit the view of the web part like RubenHerman said.  I found this out the hard way after creating over 50 doc library views to insert into a web part.  The "Selected View" drop down only displays 50 views.  It actually saves time if you don't have to create the view in the library or list.