# Web parts not getting updated in SharePoint page

Tags: list, web-part, sharepoint-addin

I have created a new web part for an announcement.Then created a page and included the announcement.Then I have modified the announcement view to show the announcements based on the expire date.

The modified view works in web part but not gets modified in the page where I included the web part.

Comment: That is "as designed". Even if you modify the view in the list, the web part will not get updated. You will need to update the view in the web part manually. Duplicate of: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/21873/changing-a-view-doesnt-automatically-reflect-on-page

Comment: What Paul said. You need to edit the page and update the view, or create a custom view that the list web part uses from the web part settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Edit the page that includes the announcement web part.

[image]

- Edit announcement web part.
- Below List view > select the announcement view that has been modified from selected view drop-down list > then click OK.

### [image]

It should be now shown with your updates.

Comment: Good news , please set it as answer if it helps and solved your issue , also should you check this http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/tour if you need to know how to do it.